# How can I query the Spamhaus DBL in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, dns

I have a Rails web application.  I want to create a class that takes an email address, say "matt@trucksandstuff.com," parses out the domain, and then checks if the domain is found in the Spamhaus DBL.  I am having no luck with the dig or host commands as described on their website and the Charon gem doesn't seem to work with their sample URL either.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  Here is what is on the website:

In response to "How can I test the DBL?" they said:

> First, the DBL follows RFC5782 for determining whether a URI zone is operational with an entry for TEST. Second, the DBL has a specific domain for testing DBL applications: dbltest.com. To test functionality of the DBL use the host or dig command to do a manual query. (If you need to look up a domain in the DBL via the web, use the domain lookup form at our Blocklist Removal Center. Do not query our website with automated tools.).

I have tried using the Charon gem, which I think should be as simple as running

```
Charon.query('dbltest.com')
```

with variations that remove the parentheses, add a space, etc.

Also tried

```
resolver = Resolv::DNS.new
name = 'dbltest.com'
resolver.getresources("#{name}.zen.spamhaus.org", Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::A)
```

in the Rails console.

Comment: Okay, added.  Any ideas now?

Comment: Are you getting errors for the things you've tried? If so, what are the errors? If not, what is the result of your attempts (i.e., what is returned from the service)?

Comment: I have figured out a way to do a DNS lookup on the command line "host dbltest.com.dbl.spamhaus.org" that works, so now my issue is just that I need to figure out how to get an equivalent DNS lookup mechanism to the command line "host" command into Rails...if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Zen database is only for IP addresses. The DBL list is for hostnames. Therefore Charon (Zen query) only works with IP addresses. To test hostnames, query them with `Resolv` and `dbl.spamhouse.org`:

```
def is_spammer?(host)
  !Resolv::DNS.new.getresources("#{host}.dbl.spamhaus.org",
                                Resolv::DNS::Resource::IN::A).empty?
end

is_spammer?('dbltest.com')
=> true
is_spammer?('google.com')
=> false
```